# Undefined reference to ros::init

Tags: ros, add-dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most of the similar questions pointed to the package's CMakeList.txt .  As far as I can tell, it's as it should be:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(random_walk)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
 roscpp
 geometry_msgs
 sensor_msgs
)


message("catkin libraries" ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
catkin_package()

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(random_walk src/random_walk.cpp)
target_link_libraries(random_walk ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(random_walk beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

Packages.xml has the dependencies

```
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
<run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
```

Rosdep said all dependencies are installed.  I performed a clean prior to trying to make, but I can't compile something as simple as:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
int main (int argc, char **argv ) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "random_walk");
}
```

Without seeing

> In function `main':   random_walk.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to` ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'

[This source](https://cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/agitr-letter-pubsub.pdf) says "If you see errors from catkin_make that the header ros/ros.h cannot be found, or “undefined reference” errors on ros::init or other ROS functions, the most likely reason is that your CMakeLists.txt does not correctly declare a dependency on roscpp." I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any ideas?

---

Verbose Output of Make

```
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/gary/catkin_ws/src -B/home/gary/catkin_ws/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 random_walk
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gary/catkin_ws/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/gary/catkin_ws/src -B/home/gary/catkin_ws/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/gary/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles 1
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 random_walk/CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gary/catkin_ws/build'
make -f random_walk/CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/build.make random_walk/CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gary/catkin_ws/build'
cd /home/gary/catkin_ws/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/gary/catkin_ws/src /home/gary/catkin_ws/src/random_walk /home/gary/catkin_ws/build /home/gary/catkin_ws/build/random_walk /home/gary/catkin_ws/build/random_walk/CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gary/catkin_ws/build'
make -f random_walk/CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/build.make random_walk/CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gary/catkin_ws/build'
Linking CXX executable /home/gary/catkin_ws/devel/lib/random_walk/random_walk
cd /home/gary/catkin_ws/build/random_walk && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/src/random_walk.cpp.o  -o /home/gary/catkin_ws/devel/lib/random_walk/random_walk -rdynamic /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/indigo/lib/librostime.so -lboost_date_time /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libcpp_common.so -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread -lconsole_bridge -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/indigo/lib 
CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/src/random_walk.cpp.o: In function `main':
random_walk.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [/home/gary/catkin_ws/devel/lib/random_walk/random_walk] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gary/catkin_ws/build'
make[2]: *** [random_walk/CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gary/catkin_ws/build'
make[1]: *** [random_walk/CMakeFiles/random_walk.dir/rule] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gary/catkin_ws/build'
make: *** [random_walk] Error 2
Base path: /home/gary/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/gary/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/gary/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/gary/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/gary/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/gary/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 random_walk VERBOSE=1" in "/home/gary/catkin_ws/build"
####
Invoking "make -j1 random_walk VERBOSE=1" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226719/undefined-reference-to-ros::init/) by [fantabulum](https://answers.ros.org/users/25961/fantabulum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-02-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-02-15**:
`catkin_make -j1 your_package_name VERBOSE=1 &> temp.txt` and inspect temp.txt to see if the libraries are in it.  Also you could add a `message("catkin libraries " ${catkin_LIBRARIES})` to your CMakeLists.txt and inspect that (it is less messy than looking at the /usr/bin/c++ line.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-15**:
I would also use `#include <ros/ros.h>` (note the `<>` instead of `""`)
Edit: Nvm, that shouldn't matter.

**Comment by [fantabulum](https://answers.ros.org/users/25961/fantabulum/) on 2016-02-16**:
@lucasw I added the verbose output, not exactly sure what I'm looking for.  Interesting note, this project was in a new workspace I created; I tried again in the workspace I created in the tutorials and it worked.  I went back through the tutorials and have yet to find anything missing.

**Comment by [fantabulum](https://answers.ros.org/users/25961/fantabulum/) on 2016-02-16**:
I built a new workspace from scratch (again).  I can't think of anything I did differently this time than last, but I can no longer reproduce the issue.  Should this question be closed or deleted?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
Post your last comment as an answer, then tick the checkmark next to it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
As to your issue: this could've been an issue with CMake caching certain variables in `CMakeCache.txt`.

**Comment by [fantabulum](https://answers.ros.org/users/25961/fantabulum/) on 2016-02-17**:
Maybe so. I originally had the CMakeList lines in the wrong order.  I had hoped `catkin_make clean` would have fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even though this was a new workspace, I created another one from scratch.  In the workspace I was working in at the time, I originally had the CMakeList lines out of order.  Running `catkin_make clean` didn't have an affect on my issue. After creating a new workspace, I copied the random_walk folder that is verbatim to what I have posted above and the problem magically vanished.

```
mkdir -p ~/test_space/src
cd ~/test_space/src/
catkin_init_workspace

cd ..
catkin_make
# /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash already sourced in .bashrc
source devel/setup.bash
cp -r ~/other_wksp_path/src/random_walk ./src/
catkin_make random_walk
```

---

Originally posted by [fantabulum](https://answers.ros.org/users/25961/fantabulum/) with karma: 21 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-03-23**:
in catkin_ws `rm -rf build devel install` ought to work as a 'superclean' that maybe would have also solved your problem.  The only thing left over that could mess up your build would maybe be an old or somehow corrupted catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt, rm and catkin_init_workspace to make a new one.